# Simple use of dynamic memory in loop causes bad_alloc

Tags: c++, mingw, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's say I have a really simple loop like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        char* c = new char[32];

        std::cout << i << " " << c[0] << std::endl;

        delete[] c;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see at the beginning of the loop I allocate some memory with new operator. I print it out and delete it. If i run this code it works but at one point it stops and throws std::bad_alloc.

I don't understand why that happens. It shouldn't run out of memory since it's freeing it every time with delete. If there was enough memory for the program to go through the loop once or twice it should be enough memory for it to loop indefinitely. And it's just 32 bytes.

I tried to run this on two different computers and each does a different number of loops before it breaks.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
 I'm using mingw g++ (gcc) 4.8.1 on Windows 8

Comment: Sure this is the [minimal program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you have shown here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, i'll add _int main_ and the _return 0_ at the end to make this clear.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please specify your platform, compiler version and compilation/linking options.

Comment: This snippet has undefined behavior, because you read c[0] without first writing to it.

Comment: @Daniel I think new automatically initializes char.

Comment: @Adam27X God I hope not. Technically, pretty much any implementation would only leave "garbage" values in it with no other negative consequences. But undefined behavior is one of those weird things that "anything could happen" when you encounter it.

Comment: @Adam27X No it does not. You would need to add `()` to value initialize the array.

Comment: It's also possible that console into which you print eats your memory if it keeps all the history (for example QtCreator IDE seems to work like that). Try removing `cout`.

Comment: You said "at one point". _What_ point? What is the value of `i`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I bet it overflows (for 64 bit maybe no :/).

Comment: @doc: I don't see that causing a `bad_alloc` in this program.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, I meant you might not see actual value of `i` for which `bad_alloc` happened. But as OP explained the problem it's irrelevant now.

Comment: @doc: Oh, right. Possibly. But unlikely - it would take a very very very long time for an integer to grow from 0 to overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.
I was using Microsoft Application Verifier for something and I accidentally left the exe selected for testing.
And since the low resource simulation test was enabled it simulated the low-memory conditions.

I didn't realize the verifier works even when it's window is closed. I figured it might be it when I tried to compile the program with different parameters and accidentally changed the output filename.
Changing the filename made the program work, so I remembered that I pointed the verifier towards the original exe earlier.

I feel silly now.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as "no longer able to reproduce" because, well, that's the case. But you should accept this answer, and it gets a +1 from me, and well done for figuring it out. :)

Comment: @doc I tried, but it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days".

Comment: @quipe: Right, so do it in two days!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That question and answer might be useful for future research, and _"no longer able to reproduce"_ just shadows the reason. I'm not sure how to improve the question about this point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You can't, which is why I voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking if you're doing anything wrong.

Technically, your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) since you're reading `c[0]` that hasn't been initialised.

Other that this, your code is perfectly fine. I suspect that the odd memory behaviour will persist even after you've fixed the UB (please try it!) If it does persist, this means that the issue has nothing to do with your code and is likely a (rather strange) property of your compiler and/or the runtime library.

I tested your code on my computer, and I cannot reproduce the behaviour:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
```

Comment: strange property called bug :)

Comment: @doc: Personally, I would tend to agree. However, given that it's likely not in violation of any spec, this is open to debate (and I going to rule myself out of that debate :)).